# Flash Message slideDown is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I'm running a Python Flask app and giving the user some feedback when actions are taken by using a flash message which drops down. It takes two arguments, a message and a Boostrap type of alert (success, warning, etc). It works on my local machine but since I've uploaded it to PythonAnywhere I get the following message:

> Routee.js:627 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: alert.alert(...).slideDown is not a function
>   at flash (Routee.js:627)
>   at Routee.js:646

Line 646 is:

```
alert.alert().slideDown(300)
```

The whole flash function is as below. Perhaps there is a better way of doing it, I'm not sure. I can't figure out why it works locally and not once uploaded.

```
function flash(message, type) {
  console.log(message, type)
  alert = jQuery("#alert")//.alert();
  alert.html(message)// change the message
  alert.attr('class','alert alert-' + type)
  alert.alert().slideDown(300)
  setTimeout(function () {
    alert.alert().slideUp(300)
  }, 1500)
}
```

Comment: The error implies that the library which adds the `alert()` method to jQuery has not been loaded. Check the console to ensure that all referenced scripts have loaded on your remote version.

Comment: @AdityaBhave the `alert` variable holds a reference to the `#alert` element already.

Comment: Which library are you using for `alert` ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes.. I was referring to calling `.alert()` function to make it an actual alert. Usuallly jQuery plugins follow this practice. But I see that is happening further in the code already.

Answer (score 0):

@Rory McCrossan , my online templates were referencing an old version of JQuery where alerts are not possible. Changed it to the latest version and hey presto.

Thanks All